# TypeError : string indices must be integers (Python)

Tags: python, json, mongodb

I am getting `TypeError: string indices must be integers` when trying to iterate over JSON with the code below. I tried to find the answer in multiple other threads, but with no luck.

This is the beginning of my JSON:

```
    '?xml': {
    '@version': '1.0',
    '@encoding': 'ISO-8859-1'
},
'scores': {
    '@sport': 'soccer',
    '@updated': '28.12.2020 04:49:21',
    'category': [{
        '@name': 'Africa: Caf Champions League - Qualification',
        '@gid': '19297',
        '@id': '1513',
        '@file_group': 'africa',
        '@iscup': 'False',
        'matches': {
            '@date': 'Dec 28',
            '@formatted_date': '28.12.2020',
            'match': {
                '@status': '19:45',
                '@timer': '',
                '@date': 'Dec 28',
                '@formatted_date': '28.12.2020',
                '@time': '19:45',
                '@commentary_available': '1513',
                '@venue': '',
                '@v': '0',
                '@static_id': '2938748',
                '@fix_id': '3445943',
                '@id': '3792777',
                'localteam': {
                    '@name': 'MC Alger',
                    '@goals': '?',
                    '@id': '5784'
                },
                'visitorteam': {
                    '@name': 'Sfaxien',
                    '@goals': '?',
                    '@id': '16927'
                },
                'events': None,
```

This is the Python code I am running:

```
import urllib.request, json, random, pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
db = client["gameDB"]
collection = db["players"]

with urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.myjsonfile.com") as url:
    data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
    #print(data)

league_id = 0
league_name = ''
match_id = 0
match_name = ''

for league in data['scores']['category']:
    league_id = league['@id']
    league_name = league['@name']

    
    
    
    for match in league['matches']['match']:
        
        match_id = match['@static_id']
        match_name = match['localteam']['@name']

        print({"{} {} {} {}".format(league_id, league_name, match_id, match_name)})
```

and this is the error I am getting:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/testScript.py", line 30, in <module>
    match_id = match['@static_id']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

The reason I am confused is that it works on some code but not on other and the code looks the same like:

```
'@static_id': '2938748',
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It seem that in the instance where the error is thrown, "match" is a string, maybe add a print(match) in front of it an post the part of the json where it happens.

Comment: `match['@static_id']` only works when `match` is a dict, not a list. But this error is telling you that `match` is a list. You need to dig into that and debug it, use print statements, IDE, figure out why.

Comment: Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Answer (score 1):

Take a cloese look at what you are actually looping over here:

```
for match in league['matches']['match']:
    match_id = match['@static_id']
    match_name = match['localteam']['@name']
```

`match` in this case are the *keys* of the `match` dict, i.e. `'@status'`, `'@timer'`, and so on, which are *strings*. You can access characters of a string using idices in Pyhton, i.e. `'example'[1]  # 'x'`. That's where the error message is coming from. What you want instead is this:

```
match = league['matches']['match']:
match_id = match['@static_id']
match_name = match['localteam']['@name']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for match in league['matches']['match']:
    
    match_id = match['@static_id']
    match_name = match['localteam']['@name']
```

You're iterating over a dict (match) like a list. You need to iterate over it like a dictionary:

```
for key, value in data.items():
    print(key, value)
```